# What is the correct appxmanifest certificate for a UWP application for Windows 10?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, monogame, windows-store

In the package.appxmanifest for a UWP Windows 10 application, under Packaging, a testing certificate must be provided to build packages for store publication.

> MyApp_TemporaryKey.pfx

When associating an application with the store, a second certificate appears.

> MyApp_StoreKey.pfx

**Is the StoreKey.pfx meant to replace the TemporaryKey.pfx?**

I can do this by choosing it in the package.appxmanifest file.

Does the store processes the testing certificate, and put in a real one during certification? Is this is why we don't need to buy a verisigned certificate from someone such as Symantec when submitting UWP applications?

I am confused by the existence of two certificates.

This is for an application to be downloaded by consumers on the Windows 10 store. This is NOT a sideloaded application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the StoreKey.pfx meant to replace the TemporaryKey.pfx?

The `TemporaryKey.pfx` is offered by Visual Studio for testing your app. When you create package not for publishing, it will be used to sign your package and you may need to export that certificate file when you need to sideload your package on another device.

When you associate your app with Store, it gives you `StoreKey.pfx` prepared for publishing， which is not meant to replace the `TemporaryKey.pfx`. Both of them exist in your app project. You can choose each of them to sign your package.

But to upload your package for Store submission, you must use `StoreKey.pfx` in order that Dev Center can identify your package since they need to accept the package with same publisher info and other identity info as the developer account.

> Is this is why we don't need to buy a verisigned certificate from
>   someone such as Symantec when submitting UWP applications?

Yes, when using certificate like Symantec to sign a sideloaded package, it can provide more security and longer expiration time. So in most case, big enterprise purchases it to sign their line of business app which can only be installed internally. However, for Store submission, we do not need to purchase it as we have one provided by Store.

Comment: To be absolutely clear,

TemporaryKey.pfx, is for development and side loading and is attached to the appxmanifest.

StoreKey.pfx REPLACES Temporary.pfx  in the appxmanifest when submitting to the store.

A submitted app only needs the store key.